# Epicor 10 SSRS Utilizing existing "Dataworks" barcode fields

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, epicor10

With being tasked to add barcode fields in an existing SSRS report I noticed that Epicor 10 has included some built in "dataworks 39" barcode fields that are displayed as "CALC_BCMTLQUEUE" for example. The barcode fields have an prefix of "BC". Now my question is, is it possible to create or apply more barcode fields as needed?

As I have found out by doing some research it seems type "39" is free but SSRS does not have a built in font or process for adding barcodes as it requires a third party instance to aid in having barcodes

I'v noticed that dataworks is not available as a font in the SSRS report builder but when copying over the pre-existing barcode fields designed by epicor there recognized as dataworks.

Comment: NOTE: The font file is included with the client `C:\Epicor\*\Client\DWBAR39.TTF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a copy of the dataworks barcode font. Install this on the SSRS Report Server and every Client that the report will print from. Once you install the Barcode font on the machine that you are using to develop the SSRS report, you should be able to select the font from the dropdown. This of course will be available after you restart the machine after installation of the font.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I googled around and seemed to not come across a data works font download. I'm guessing data works is integrated with Epicor and maybe its possible I could find a TTF File locally?

Comment: Actually I found the TTF file for the dataworks 39 and added it to the windows font directory and restarted the report server. But when editing a report its not listed in the fonts available oddly.

Comment: @tfenwick11 is the server the machine you are trying to develop on?

Comment: Yes its the report instance.

Comment: @tfenwick11 In that case, i would try to download another bar code font to verify that there isn't something wrong with the file you found. Installing a font for SSRS is pretty straight forward some I'm not sure whats causing it to not show up. try downloading this Code 3 of 9 font. https://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

Comment: i made a user error and realized the report builder instance i was using was local to my pc and not the report server per say. After copying the dataworks 39 from the server to my pc. The barcodes show up correctly. Question: Will barcodes still display in a field even though there is no value? It seems i am getting fields with small barcodes but they contain no data?

Comment: @tfenwick11 not sure, never tested that. If your having issues with that. Id suggest just hiding the field if `Fields!YourFieldName.Value = "" OR IsNothing(Fields!YourFieldName.Value)`